# Angular Http Post to .Net Core

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Trying to make to Post to a .net core from Angular. The get operation can be done smoothly, but the post operation can not be performed.
It is seen when debug is done that the Api method is never called.
Responce Response {_body: "", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers,}

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StokKartsController : Controller
{
    private readonly StokKartContext _context;

    public StokKartsController(StokKartContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<StokKart> deneme()
    {
        return _context.stok.ToList();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult StokKartEkle([FromBody] StokKart stokKart)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        _context.stok.Add(stokKart);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(stokKart);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class StokKart
{
    [Key]
    public string urunKodu { get; set; }
    public string urunAdi { get; set; }
    public string urunGrubu { get; set; }
    public string ureticiKodu { get; set; }
    public int barkodKodu { get; set; }
    public string uretici { get; set; }
    public string urunTipi { get; set; }
    public string marka { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string birim { get; set; }
    public int kdv { get; set; }
    public float alisFiyati { get; set; }
    public float satisFiyati { get; set; }
    //public bool? serinoTakibiYap { get; set; }
}
```

TypeScript:

```
 import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 @Component ({
     selector: 'stokKarti',
     templateUrl: './stokKarti.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./stokKarti.component.css']
 })
 export class StokKartiComponent implements OnInit {

      stokKarts: IStokKart[];
      stokKart: IStokKart;
      headers: Headers;
      http: Http;
      options: RequestOptions;
      baseUrl: string;

      constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
          this.http = http;
          this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
          let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     }
     ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/StokKarts/deneme').subscribe(result => {
            this.stokKarts = result.json() as IStokKart[];
            console.log(result);
        }, error => console.error(error));       
     }

     public urunKayit(e: any) {      
         //e.preventDefault();
         //this.stokKart.urunKodu = e.path[12].getElementById("urunKodu").value;
         //this.stokKart.urunTipi = e.path[12].getElementById("urunTipi").value;

         let stoks: IStokKart = <IStokKart>{
            "urunKodu": "U01",
            "urunAdi": " ",
            "urunGrubu": " ",
            "ureticiKodu": " ",
            "barkodKodu": 1,
            "uretici": " ",
            "urunTipi": " ",
            "marka": " ",
            "model": " ",
            "birim": " ",
            "kdv": 1,
            "alisFiyati": 2.5,
            "satisFiyati": 3.5
        };
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/StokKarts/StokKartEkle', JSON.stringify(stoks), this.options)
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res), error => console.error(error));
     }
   }

   interface IStokKart {
         urunKodu: string;
         urunAdi: string;
         urunGrubu: string;
         ureticiKodu: string;
         barkodKodu: number;
         uretici: string
         urunTipi: string;
         marka: string;
         model: string;
         birim: string;
         kdv: number;
         alisFiyati: number;
         satisFiyati: number;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered that this might be a CORS issue?

Comment: try send simply "stoks" -not "JSON.stringify(stoks)"- your post expect an object-. By the way, you must think use the new HttpClient and not the old Htpp

Comment: I have considered that this might be a CORS issue .[link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors                    
I made the steps in these tutorials step by step.  
I tried send simply "stoks".But there was no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your properties are not nullable, so if you want to receive null or white spaces, you should set up your class like this:

```
public class StokKart
{
    [Key]
    public string urunKodu { get; set; }
    public string? urunAdi { get; set; }
    public string? urunGrubu { get; set; }
    public string? ureticiKodu { get; set; }
    public int barkodKodu { get; set; }
    public string? uretici { get; set; }
    public string? urunTipi { get; set; }
    public string? marka { get; set; }
    public string? model { get; set; }
    public string? birim { get; set; }
    public int kdv { get; set; }
    public float alisFiyati { get; set; }
    public float satisFiyati { get; set; }
    //public bool? serinoTakibiYap { get; set; }
}
```

and since you're having an Interface in your angular app, you can set your post method of type IStockart, like the following (correct me if I'm wrong, I noticed that your endpoint in the API and Angular don't match, so I changed it the angular side):

```
let stoks: IStokKart = {
            "urunKodu": "U01",
            "urunAdi": " ",
            "urunGrubu": " ",
            "ureticiKodu": " ",
            "barkodKodu": 1,
            "uretici": " ",
            "urunTipi": " ",
            "marka": " ",
            "model": " ",
            "birim": " ",
            "kdv": 1,
            "alisFiyati": 2.5,
            "satisFiyati": 3.5
        };
        this.http.post<IStokKart>(this.baseUrl + 'api/StokKarts', stoks, this.options)
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res), error => console.error(error));
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: Correct, but still in the web api, you should specify if the value can be null or not by adding interrogation mark.